# Opencv Python SVM + HOG

Tags: python, opencv, svm, object-detection

I am working on an object detector in Opencv and python. I am currently experimenting with several variants for my problem. I've noticed that detectmultiscale () as well as predict () seem to use only one processor. This makes my program very slow.
I wanted to ask if it is possible to distribute the tasks on several processors.

I made this simple programm to detect my object, using my trained classifier. Here i'm scaling the full image and then applying sliding windows. After that i use predict to detect objects in the current window. This is very slow, but it uses only 25% of my cpu. Is there a solution to speed it up, by using more ressources?

```
# loop over the image pyramid
for resized in pyramid(image, scale=1.5):
    # loop over the sliding window for each layer of the pyramid
    for (x, y, window) in sliding_window(resized, stepSize=32, windowSize (winW, winH)):
         # if the window does not meet our desired window size, ignore it
         if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW: 
         continue
         # now comes the prediction as well as marking the detected objects with rectangles
```